# remove the space in the text overleaf

Tags: math-mode, xetex

I have a code like the following,

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\begin{document}
$\boldsymbol{\mathcal{X}}_\mathrm{m}\!= \![{\boldsymbol{X}_{\mathrm{m},1}}, {\boldsymbol{X}_{\mathrm{m},2}}, \! \cdots\!, {\boldsymbol{X}_{\mathrm{m},N}} ]^\top$,
$\boldsymbol{\mathcal{X}}_\mathrm{md}=\![{\boldsymbol{X}_{\mathrm{md},1}},\, {\boldsymbol{X}_{\mathrm{md},2}}, \!\cdots\!, \, {\boldsymbol{X}_{\mathrm{md},N}} ]^\top$,  mass as $\boldsymbol{\mathcal{Y}}_\mathrm{m}\!= \![{\boldsymbol{Y}_{\mathrm{m},1}},\! {\boldsymbol{Y}_{\mathrm{m},2}},\!\cdots\!, {\boldsymbol{Y}_{\mathrm{m},N}} ]^\top$,$\!\boldsymbol{\mathcal{Y}}_\mathrm{md}\!= [{\boldsymbol{Y}_{\mathrm{md},1}}, \,{\boldsymbol{Y}_{\mathrm{md},2}}, \!\cdots\!, \, {\boldsymbol{Y}_{\mathrm{md},N}} ]^\top$
\end{document}
```

But in the text, there are a lot of space. Could you help me to remove these spaces? thanks

[image]

I don't know why my figure is not showing.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  There isn't really enough information here; for example, are you using a document class with a very narrow width, or two columns?  You should almost never need `\!` to remove space, and it won't work here.  Please provide a small compilable example, to allow potential helpers to copy-and-paste something that they can experiment with directly.

Comment: Problem solved? Consider upvoting and accepting the provided answers. If the problem is not solved, then at least leave a comment below the answer and explain the remaining issue.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Thank you for following up. I have to change the way which I have formulated to solve the problem. For this reason, I did not upvote any solution.

Comment: Ok, please keep in mind that the others cannot know what you are up to when you do not communicate (for several weeks) :). This is just a head-up in order to help you to get help in the future (otherwise you might de-motivate some users including me). A very good reference for beginners is https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228. Maybe read and follow it before you ask a new question, again, just a heads-up.

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime your code is different from the image:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}

\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{parskip}


\begin{document}

$\boldsymbol{\mathcal{X}}_\mathrm{m}\!= \![{\boldsymbol{X}_{\mathrm{m},1}}, {\boldsymbol{X}_{\mathrm{m},2}}, \! \cdots\!, {\boldsymbol{X}_{\mathrm{m},N}} ]^\top$,
$\boldsymbol{\mathcal{X}}_\mathrm{md}=\![{\boldsymbol{X}_{\mathrm{md},1}},\, {\boldsymbol{X}_{\mathrm{md},2}}, \!\cdots\!, \, {\boldsymbol{X}_{\mathrm{md},N}} ]^\top$,  mass as $\boldsymbol{\mathcal{Y}}_\mathrm{m}\!= \![{\boldsymbol{Y}_{\mathrm{m},1}},\! {\boldsymbol{Y}_{\mathrm{m},2}},\!\cdots\!, {\boldsymbol{Y}_{\mathrm{m},N}} ]^\top$,$\!\boldsymbol{\mathcal{Y}}_\mathrm{md}\!= [{\boldsymbol{Y}_{\mathrm{md},1}}, \,{\boldsymbol{Y}_{\mathrm{md},2}}, \!\cdots\!, \, {\boldsymbol{Y}_{\mathrm{md},N}} ]^\top$
\end{document}
```

[image]

and I not see more spaces. It is very important that you add a complete compilable example with all package like my example.

Comment: Thanks. You right. However, since this is one part of a long document, I don't know which is the right package for this equation to add. Yes, your code does not have any space. But just I copied that, and it has spaces yet.

Comment: @Sadcow You can remove one to one every package and compile it. Probably there is some package that have a conflict with other packages. Thus it is very complicated to understand the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Although it makes no difference to LaTeX, you have an extra space in “…\!= \!…”, probably you wanted: “\!=\!”. But you should rather replace all the hand-crafted spacing `\!` and `\,` with spaces and let (La)TeX handle the spacing…

LaTeX is trying to justify your text.  If you add:

```latex
\begin{flushleft}
 <your_code_here>
\end{flushleft}
```

the wide spacing will vanish.

[image: fixed]

Full code:

```latex
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\begin{document}
\begin{flushleft}
$\boldsymbol{\mathcal{X}}_\mathrm{m} = [{\boldsymbol{X}_{\mathrm{m},1}}, {\boldsymbol{X}_{\mathrm{m},2}}, \cdots , {\boldsymbol{X}_{\mathrm{m},N}} ]^\top$,
$\boldsymbol{\mathcal{X}}_\mathrm{md}= [{\boldsymbol{X}_{\mathrm{md},1}}, {\boldsymbol{X}_{\mathrm{md},2}}, \cdots , {\boldsymbol{X}_{\mathrm{md},N}} ]^\top$, mass as $\boldsymbol{\mathcal{Y}}_\mathrm{m} = [{\boldsymbol{Y}_{\mathrm{m},1}}, {\boldsymbol{Y}_{\mathrm{m},2}}, \cdots , {\boldsymbol{Y}_{\mathrm{m},N}} ]^\top$,$ \boldsymbol{\mathcal{Y}}_\mathrm{md} = [{\boldsymbol{Y}_{\mathrm{md},1}}, {\boldsymbol{Y}_{\mathrm{md},2}}, \cdots , {\boldsymbol{Y}_{\mathrm{md},N}} ]^\top$
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Typed (input) spaces in math are ignored; spacing is entirely governed by TeX based on its internal rules (Appendix G of the TeXbook) and explicitly coded spaces.  Typed space-bar spaces are sometimes added by authors to make the input easier to read.  That said, your example either uses explicit line breaks or a variation on `\raggedright`, which you haven't mentioned.

Comment: You are right about the spacing, of course.  Nothing hidden except "a5paper" in the options of an "article"… I added my code above!

Comment: Thank you for the details.  `flushleft` is equivalent to `\raggedright` and accounts for the sensible line breaks.  But you really should remove all the `\!` because the spacing around the equal signs should be a little more generous.

Comment: I tried to respect the original author's code as much as possible (and it had the `\!`).  But I'll change it and add a comment.